# Chrome browser extension alignment of image links side by side (horizontally)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to display images as link side by side. The code works fine when executed on browser. But the images are displayed vertically when loaded into extension.
I can't figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<html>
<body>
<!--
<div class="imgContainer">
 <a href="popup.html">
<img border="0" src="images/a.png" height="30" width="30">
</a>

</div>

 <div class="imgContainer">
 <a href="popup2.html">
<img border="0" src="images/b.png" height="30" width="30">
</a>
</div>-->
<!--<div id="imgContainer">
<form action="/popup.html">

  <input type="image" src="images/a.png" alt="Submit" width="30" height="30">
</form>


<form action="/popup2.html">

  <input type="image" src="images/b.png" alt="Submit" width="30" height="30">
</form>
</div>-->

<div>
<a href="popup.html" >
  <img src="images/a.png"  width="30" height="30" /></a>
  </div>
  <div>
  
 <a href="popup.html"> <img src="images/b.png"  width="30" height="30" /></a>
</div>
  <!--<button type="submit">
<img src="images/a.png" height="30" width="30"/>
</button>
<button type="submit">
<img src="images/a.png" height="30" width="30"/>
</button>-->
<style>
.imgContainer{
display: inline-flex;
}
div {
    display: inline-flex;
}
<!--body { 
                
                overflow-x: hidden; 
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
                font-size: 12px; 
            }
</style>

</body>
</html>
```

[extension pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfhf1.png)

Comment: Yes! tried it as well
Same issue again

Comment: have you tried giving some width to your parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="display:flex">
            <div>
                <a href="popup.html" ><img src="images/a.png" width="30" height="30" /></a>
            </div> 
             <div>
                 <a href="popup.html"> <img src="images/b.png"  width="30" height="30" /></a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```